# How to replace Unsafe.objectFieldOffset?

Tags: java, java-11

I update jdk 8 to jdk 11 , how to replace  Unsafe.objectFieldOffset

```
Math.max(size, unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f) + sizeOf(f));
```

Comment: What does the code do? Also, note that you can currently still use `Unsafe` via the `jdk.unsupported` module.

Comment: the idea compilation faild,any replace idea? i found JEP 260 and VarHandle but it not  support objectFieldOffset

Comment: What was the compilation error?

Comment: can not found the symbol Unsafe

Comment: Interesting. I don't have that problem in OpenJDK 12. As I said, the class is still available via the `jdk.unsupported` module (the module even `opens sun.misc`). Regarding a possible replacement for getting the field offset, I'm not aware of one.

Comment: For a replacement option, we'd need to know what you are using this for, as there is no 1-to-1 replacement afaik.

Answer (score 5):

`sun.misc.Unsafe` is a [Critical Internal API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) which was not encapsulated in JDK 9:

> These APIs are thus accessible by default to code on the class path,
>   and accessible to code in modules if those modules declare dependences
>   upon the `jdk.unsupported` module.

So, you can just continue using it.